# I can't use ngmodel when using forms

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-components

I am not using ngModel for form. I made all the definitions, I made the CommonModule and FormsModule definitions.
[image]
[image]

I made all the definitions.I can't see if I'm missing something else

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="Submit(form)">
```

I made it into the form definition

Answer (score 0):

Include `FormModule` in your Module.

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Add `FormsModule` to `imports`

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
       FormsModule
    ],
})
```

Make sure to add FormsModule to imports: [] of the module where you use ngModel.

Comment: no if you look carefully it says formsModule

Comment: What is the name of the File You shared in the Second Screenshot??

Comment: app.module.ts screenshot

Comment: Can you stop and rebuild the app once?

Comment: Angular language service is giving that error because it is old 15.2. I already opened a question because of this on stackoverflow. I deleted the visual studio code application and reinstalled it.